# gtag custom dimensions not being picked up by Google Analytics

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I am trying to integrate a custom dimension using Angular4 and Google Analytics.  I've seen similar topics, but nothing that deals exactly with this issue.

In GA I have set up the custom dimension:

[image]

It shows with index 1:

[image]

In `index.html` I have:

```html
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxx-xxxxx"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date()); 
    gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxx-xxxxx', {
      'custom_map': {
        'dimension1': 'userType'
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Then in `app.component.ts` I use the router event to get the page location and pass the user type:

```html
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {

    (<any>window).gtag('event', 'pageView', {
      'page_path': event.urlAfterRedirects,
      'userType': 1
    });

  }
});
```

When I visit the website I see page views in the Real Time area of GA:

[image]

I also see the event in Events:

[image]

I can see that the custom dimension is being sent in the QueryString parameters in "network" in Chrome developer console:

```html
v: 1
_v: j69
a: xxxxxxxx
t: event
_s: 10
dl: http://localhost/
dp: /member/dashboard <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< page_path
ul: en
de: UTF-8
dt: xxxxxxx
sd: 24-bit
sr: 1920x1200
vp: 1189x1073
je: 0
ec: general
ea: pageView <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< EVENT NAME
_u: xxxxx~
jid: 
gjid: 
cid: xxxx
tid: UA-xxxxx-xxxxx
_gid: xxxxxxx
gtm: u9h
cd1: 1 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< CUSTOM DIMENSION
z: 1516445861
```

I've set up a custom report to filter all users of userType 1:

[image]

However, nothing is showing.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong please?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you wait 24 hours?

Comment: No, do I need to?

Comment: If you are using Google tag manager for event tracking, you can push custom events with dimension value to datalayer. Pls refer this https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/what-is-data-layer-in-google-tag-manager/

Comment: @Dougi In standard accounts GA data delay is about 24 hours.

Comment: OooooooooK, that may well explain it then.  I'll have a look tomorrow morning.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I seem to have data in there today, so looks like that was all it was.  Sigh!  Thank you @Ms.Easy

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was just that "In standard accounts GA data delay is about 24 hours" as mentioned by @Ms.Easy.